# How do you find the difference in dates between a date selector and todays date with an error message if date is less than a certain amount of days

Tags: javascript, html, date, datediff

I am a very new learner and have been trying to learn as I go and I am completely stumped. I need to do the following and I cannot figure it out.

> 1. You have to write a function called “dateDiff” that accepts one date parameter and returns the number of days between the birthday provided and the current date.
> 2. Print “fname lname you have been breathing for ### days!” where ### is the number returned by your dateDiff() function.  Remember to convert milliseconds to days and only return the integer(whole) number of days.
>
> If the number of days is less than (365*18) then print “You are probably not old enough to take this class!”

Now, I have already created the following: (User id, Fname, Lname, Birthday,) as part of a login screen. Below is the code that I have written so far. Please be kind. This is my first crack at javascript.

Thank you!

HTML

```
<label for="birthday">Birthday:</label><br><br>
    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="datestart" value="" class="datepicker" required="" 
        placeholder="birthday" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Invalid Birthday')">
```

JS

```
var d1 = new Date();
    var d2 = new Date() 

    var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();   
    var daydiff = diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);  
    document.write(" Total number of days between <b> " + d1 + " </b> and <b> " + d2 + " </b> is: <b> " + daydiff + " days </b>" );
```

Comment: d2 should be something like var d2=new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds) and replace month year day with the input from datestart.